# I am building a google extension but I am stuck. I need to find a way to click on a text box of a page and output data to it

Tags: javascript

I just want to know how to or what function to use to Click a button on a page using JS Path but I've been looking for two days now at youtube videos and I can't get my head around it most of the time it doesn't work because functions that they tell me to use in videos don't work. For example

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
      let page = tabs[0].url;
      page.Evaluate("document.querySelector('#cboxLoadedContent > div > div.block_content > form > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > input').value = '1'")
    });
```

but the function page.Evaluate is not a function that works with google extension for me not sure why?
Can anyone help me find a way to click buttons and insert values using JS Path. Also it needs to be on the current page that is opened with the google extension present.

Comment: You're assigning a url string to page. Here is a tut https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Chrome-Extension-run-JavaScript-in-the-context-of-the-current-page

Comment: Actually is there a way to make your javascript output a piece of code to the google inspect console? Because then i can use the JS Path but just make it so that the code pastes it into the google inspect console and it should work like that. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: console.log(). To view the extension's console log, enable developer mode and then click on the background.js file of your extension.

Comment: Right but using background.js would mean that it will be going into console of the popup not of the page I am currently on. I need it to console log in the page that the google extension is currently open in. Any idea on how to do that ? Appreciate all the help I've been sitting at my desk all day trying to figure this one out.

Comment: i wonder if its possible to append a script element on the current page's DOM to execute code